# Visual studio web express 2013 with update 4 downloading stuck

Tags: web, express, visual-studio-2013

I am downloading Visual studio web express 2013 with update 4 and when acquiring KB2829760  it stuck. Then prompts that "Unable to locate package source".Please give your kind attention as this is highly important to fix and install.[image]

[image]

Comment: Um... did you check "download packages from the Internet"?

Comment: Yes. Same happens.try to download and again same error comes.